# Antonyme d'atomique dans son sens élément constitutif final

Tags: vocabulaire, synonymes, antonyme

Je cherche à dire en un mot 'qui contient des éléments plus petits'.

En opposition à atomique dans son sens indivisible : https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%84%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%82

Ce n'est pas le parfait antonyme que je cherche, puisque sécable ou divisible le serait.

J'ai pensé à 'contenant' mais il n'est pas très joli.

Contexte : développement informatique, les composants atomiques ne contiennent pas de composants. Comment qualifier ceux qui justement doivent en contenir ?

Comment: Peut-être « Composé » ?

Comment: c'est pas mal composé :) Atomique contre Composé. Validé pour moi si tu en fais une réponse. Je vérifie si composé n'a pas un sens contradictoire en informatique => ça colle. merci

Comment: Si l'on s'en réfert à l'*atomic design*, il y a plusieurs noms en fonction de la taille de l'élément en question: Molécules, Organismes, Templates, pages. Mais les 2 derniers sont très connotés web. Pourquoi donc pas "éléments moléculaires" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je fais de mon commentaire une réponse.

À mon avis, le mot « composé » pourrait faire l'affaire.

Comment: Après réflexion, je trouve que le composite est plus joli que composé. J'ai un faible pour le "ite". Mais composite **implique** que les éléments constituants soient de nature différente. composé est validé pour mon cas.

Answer (score 5):

Pas très loin d'une réponse déjà fournie par Toto, je proposerais:

> élément [composite](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/composite).
>
> *En partic. Qui est composé de plusieurs éléments ou matériaux. Une construction composite; une poudre composite.*

Composite est couramment utilisé en informatique avec ce sens, en français comme en anglais.

Voir par exemple *[composite data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type)*.

Si l’hétérogénéité que peut sembler impliquer *composite* rebute, on peut aussi utiliser

> élément [structuré](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/structur%C3%A9/1).
>
> [En parlant de constr. matérielles hum.] Dont la structure est rendue nettement perceptible, est soulignée.

[Structure](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/structure) étant défini comme suit:

> A. − [À propos d'entités fabriquées par l'homme]
>   1. Agencement, entre eux, des éléments constitutifs d'un ensemble construit, qui fait de cet ensemble un tout cohérent et lui donne son aspect spécifique

En informatique, on retrouve structure avec le mot clef *[struct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language))* du langage C et de quelques dérivés, qui définit précisément un élément composé d'un assemblage d'autres éléments qui peuvent être de même nature ou non.

Comment: C'est très joli mais comme indiqué (à plusieurs reprises) dans le lien, composite **implique** la différence de nature des éléments constituants. Ce qui n'est pas mon cas (j'ai des composés d'éléments atomiques identiques).

Comment: Ce n'est pas le cas en informatique. Une structure, que j'ai rajouté à ma réponse, est définie comme type de donnée composite quand bien même elle peut n'être constituée que d'éléments de même type.

Comment: Presque. Si on suit la traduction des pages wikipédia d'un article à l'autre, on voit que le type composite est appelé composé : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type#Composite_types & https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_(informatique)#Types_compos%C3%A9s

Comment: Ça se discute. Il y a peut-être une part d'anglicisme, mais j'ai toujours entendu parler de "type de données composites" que l'on trouve en plus grand nombre que que "type de données composées" que google books ne trouve que dans la  page de wikipedia citée. Cela dit, je ne rejette pas du tout *composé* qui est déjà une très bonne suggestion.

Comment: Honnêtement, cela sort complétement de mon niveau de français. Je vais laisser les amateurs et les experts en débattre. Encore une fois, c'est un très joli mot, merci de la suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Je vais moi aussi élaborer sur mon commentaire. L'*atomic design* définit ces composants non-élémentaires comme des molécules, des organismes, des templates ou des pages. Si l'on parle de `composants atomiques` pour les éléments indivisibles, je proposerais donc `éléments moléculaires` pour les autres. Le terme `organismes` est peut-être utilisable aussi mais je le trouve trop...organique.
Si la référence atome/molécule n'est pas souhaitée, peut-être pourrait-on parler d'`éléments complexes` ?

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a pas de terme unique ou dans certains cas  pas de terme spécifique qui fournisse une opposition explicite à « élément le plus petit » ; cela dépend du domaine particulier où on trouve ce mot.  On peut cependant presque toujours avoir recours au terme « **non-atomique** », qui lui est explicite.

Il ne semble pas y avoir de terme similaire dans le domaine de la physique. Le terme consacré pour le niveau de construction supérieur est « molécule » et donc si l'on veut établir une opposition on peut parler de **niveau atomique** et de **niveau moléculaire** ou **non atomique**.

Cette notion de l'antonyme du terme « atomique » a pris une nouvelle dimension dans le siècle dernier comme l'on s'est mis à appliquer le terme « atomique » non plus aux constituants élémentaires de la matière mais à des éléments de la logique ou de la programmation. Par exemple en logique on appelle les propositions qui ne se sont construites à partir d'aucun connecteur (et, ou, non, conditionnelle, biconditionnelle) des atomes ou des formules atomiques. Lorsque l'on combine ces formules avec d'autres au moyen des connecteurs, on parle alors de **formules composées** ou **complexes** ([réf.](https://www.lri.fr/~paulin/Logique/html/cours003.html)), les deux termes étant synonymes et explicites puisqu'ils sont définis comme signifiant « pas de la sorte la pluq élémentaire ». Il existe donc dans ce domaine un terme « antonyme ».

Dans la programmation Lisp les expressions telles que les nombres, les noms et les chaines sont appelé des atomes ou des expressions atomiques. Pour les expressions qui ne sont pas atomiques le terme est tout simplement « expression **non-atomique** », qui est évidemment explicite par construction.

Dans le cas de l'informatique aussi le terme « **non-atomique** » peut être utilisé tant qu'un terme spécifique ne s'impose pas, et même après.